# Setting carry flag in Armsim#

Tags: arm

Is there some command to set carry flag to desired value. I know that there are some ways ,e.g, C is set to 1 if the addition produced a carry (that is, an unsigned overflow), and to 0 otherwise. But that requires extra work to be done. So I was wondering if some command exists to set the carry flag, just for some debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C is set to 1 if the addition produced a carry... But that requires extra work...

On that theme, though, note that the C bit for addition is the nB bit for subtraction (i.e. logical NOT borrow), therefore a subtraction which *doesn't* underflow will also set it, and there's a real easy way to set the flags with a subtraction guaranteed not to underflow:

```
cmp  r0, r0
```

But trickery aside, if you want the flags in a specific state, it's probably best to put the appropriate value there directly, by the proper means:

```
msr  CPSR_f, #0x20000000
```